# Packing float into vec4 - how does this code work?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I am trying to study shadow mapping in WebGL. I see same piece of shader code copied in various libraries and examples that achieve this. However nowhere did I find the explanation of how it works.

The idea is to save a depth value (a single float) into the color buffer (vec4). There is a pack function that saves float to vec4 and unpack function that retrieves the float from vec4.

```
vec4 pack_depth(const in float depth)
{
    const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(256.0*256.0*256.0, 256.0*256.0, 256.0, 1.0);
    const vec4 bit_mask  = vec4(0.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0);
    vec4 res = fract(depth * bit_shift);
    res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;
    return res;
}

float unpack_depth(const in vec4 rgba_depth)
{
    const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(1.0/(256.0*256.0*256.0), 1.0/(256.0*256.0), 1.0/256.0, 1.0);
    float depth = dot(rgba_depth, bit_shift);
    return depth;
}
```

I would have imagined that packing a float into vec4 should be a trivial problem, just copy it into one of the 4 slots of vec4 and leave others unused. That's why the bit shifting logic in above code is puzzling to me.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not storing a GLSL `float` in a GLSL `vec4`. What it's doing is storing a value in a `vec4` which, when written to an RGBA8 framebuffer (32-bit value) can be read as a `vec4` and then reconstituted into the same `float` that was given previously.

If you did what you suggest, just writing the floating-point value to the red channel of the framebuffer, you'd only get 8 bits of accuracy. With this method, you get all 32-bits working for you.

Comment: I see. It wasn't apparent to me that color buffer internally stores the color value as 4 integers even though we feed it a vec4. If that is so, then the above code makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking the conversion is to a 32 bit fixed point number - not a floating point number.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested into the nitty-gritty details of how these routines work I suggest you to read [my blog post](http://marcodiiga.github.io/encoding-normalized-floats-to-rgba8-vectors). I'm adding some details here on how that code works and to address some possible use cases.

As you probably figured out, that code is encoding a normalized float value to a `vec4`. OpenGL ES 2.0 or WebGL (at the time of writing), might make use of those pack/unpack routines to provide 32 bit precision floating points via `RGBA8` textures ([more on this in the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/)).

Even with the extension posted by Mikael (`OES_texture_float`) it might be necessary (for debugging purposes for instance) to dump full 32 bit precision normalized floating points and as described in the spec `readPixels` is currently limited by the following

> Only two combinations of format and type are accepted. The first is format RGBA and type UNSIGNED_BYTE. The second is an implementation-chosen format.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer above, you might be interested in the floating point texture extension described here:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/

Note that there are hardware/software setups out there where this extension doesn't exist/run, but if it do it sure is a good extension. My experience is that it's fast as well. If you use this, you can use the remaining three channels to store other information, such as color from a projected texture.