# OpenGL ES2.0 glReadPixels() read data from renderbuffer through framebuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am doing off-screen processing using opengl es2.0 on Android.

I created a renderbuffer, and attached it to a framebuffer FBO, after rendering to the FBO, I try to get the pixels from that FBO by getReadPixels() method. But I got nothing.

The code is shown below:

```
GLuint resultFBO;// FBO
    GLuint rboId;  //render buffer id
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, image_width, image_height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &resultFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, resultFBO);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    //LOGH("Single FBO setup successfully.");
} else {
    LOGH("Problem in setup FBO texture: %d .", status);
}

//After render to the FBO 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, resultFBO);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageSetData);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you read the 16-bit depth buffer into a ubyte array?

Comment: @ChristianRau I tried with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT when call glRenderbufferStorage, but that will failed with errors.

Comment: Well yeah, so what? `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` is probably a good idea, but why read it into a ubyte array?

Comment: And by the way, what is *"nothing"* at all? How do you check the contents of `imageSetData` and what does it actually contain (since it cannot contain *"nothing"*)?

Comment: @ChristianRau  actually after I transfer the data to imageSetData, I will show it on screen.  Previously I render to texture, and use getReadPixels(), I can get and see the image. now I am going to render to renderbuffer, getReadPixels() method doesn't transfer any data to my imageSetData.

Comment: *"actually after I transfer the data to imageSetData, I will show it on screen."* - **so does it show black, or what?**

Comment: @ChristianRau  imageSetData has original data, the original data not changed at all. if work properly, i can see a new image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not `glReadPixels()` from `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` in OpenGL ES 2.0. Only from the color buffer. See API Reference [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

---

```
void glReadPixels(  GLint x,
    GLint y,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    GLvoid * data);
```

**format**
    Specifies the format of the pixel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`, and `GL_RGBA`

---

**Workaround1:** If precision is not that important, you can write depth to one of the 8bit color channels instead.

**Workaround2:** You can write depth into the RGBA channels by packing the float into a vec4: See for example [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882716/packing-float-into-vec4-how-does-this-code-work).

**Workaround3:** You can try the [OES_depth_texture](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt) extension and, if supported,  render to a depth texture instead.

Comment: But when I need render to render buffer through FBO, when I allocate memory for the render buffer, I use `glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, image_width, image_height);
` here I am using `GL_DEPTH_COMMPNET16`, so I think I cannot use GL_RGB to read pixels. What do you think?

Comment: I linked to a thread that explains how you can pack a depth float into a RGBA vec4.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay, Can I ask you another question? regarding the precision in shaders, my code works well on desktop version of openg GL, but when I port to Android, I found there are some artifacts in the result image, the white color becomes green, I used RGB32 format on desktop, but I used RGB format (each channel 8 bits) on Android, is this the problem?