# GLKit, Opengl ES 3.0, get depth with glReadPixels

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

Ho can I get distance point on screen? 
Here is code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];

    if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16;

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    shader = [[BaseEffect alloc] initWithVertexShader:@"Shader.vsh"
                                       fragmentShader:@"Shader.fsh"];

    // setup projection and model matrix
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    [shader prepareToDraw];
    // draw point

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pointsCount);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint tapLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    GLfloat depth = 0;
    glReadPixels(tapLoc.x, tapLoc.y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
    NSLog(@"Depth %f", depth);
}
```

All draws perfectly, but I can't get distance to drew points.

### Edit:

I log depth, also experimenting with color. Color is reading only whith this arguments:

```
glReadPixels(p.x, p.y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
```

When use GL_FLOAT, rgb can not be read.
I also try get values after drawing:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // preparing and drawing

    if (testDepthPoint.x != 0) {
        [self testDepth:testDepthPoint];
        testDepthPoint = CGPointZero;
    }
}

- (void)testDepth:(CGPoint)p {
    GLfloat depth = -99.0;
    glReadPixels(p.x, p.y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
    NSLog(@"Depth %f", depth); // always log -99.0
}
```

Not worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 not supported to read `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` from buffer. More info here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805281/820795

It works for Opengl ES 3.0

In ES 3.0 and later,there is support for depth textures. Using this, you can get the depth using the following steps.

- Render the scene to an FBO, using a texture as the depth attachment.
- Render a screen sized quad with a shader that samples the depth
  texture generated in the previous step, and writes the value to the
  color buffer.
- Use glReadPixels() on the color buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should be looking at `depth` instead of `pixelColor`, you also need to be aware of timing, which should be after the frame has completed drawing and before the submit of the next frame.

Comment: Doesn't work =(
With `pixelColor` was experiment, depth anyway not read

Comment: If glReadPixels was successful, you'd get a number between 0 and 1. At this point you need to look at why this is failing. Use glGetError to see what's going on. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml

Comment: Thanks, seams OpenGL ES 3.0 doesn't support reading depth component, only GL_RGBA.

Comment: I wondered about that, but there were enough references to actually read the depth buffer that I couldn't be sure. Perhaps there's a workaround though, because you could unproject the touch point and project a ray in world space for collision(/depth) detection instead.

Comment: As long as you can bind the depth buffer, you can also still do some shenanigans to calculate the depth value from the RGBA values. The formula is going to be something like R * (1/255*256)  + G * (1/256) for a 16 bit depth buffer.

Comment: Thanks) also we can use all channels in RGBA to represent distance to point https://stackoverflow.com/q/9882716/820795 Seams I will use ray approach. If it will be to slow, will move to use RGBA buffer.