# three.js water surface following with object

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I'm using ["threejs-examples-webgl-gpgpu_water"](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_water.html) and would like to put an object on the surface following this surface which means sync with the vertex displacement on the point where the object is.

I cannot find out how to get the current height of coordinates x,y in the water surface. I guess the image is calculated in the shader and there is no access to the intermediate value of the deformed water surface. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The height values of the water are stored in a texture that is part of a render target so you could use `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels ( renderTarget, x, y, width, height, buffer )` to pull out the height of the water at a particular point.

Unfortunately that texture is a floating point texture and there's no way to directly read a floating point texture in WebGL into JavaScript.

What you'd need to do is render that floating point texture into a non-floating point RGBA 8bit texture/rendertarget while quantizing it into some other representation using some code related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490427/webgl-packing-a-float-into-v4).

In pseudo code

```
// at init time

.. make rendertarget with RGBA,UNSIGNED_BYTE texture

// at render time

.. render `gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( heightmapVariable ).texture;` 
.. into your render target using a shader that converts the
.. floating point height values in RGBA like the example above

// read out a pixel from your render target
var heightData = new Uint8Array(4);
var x = ...  // compute which pixel you need to read
var y = ...  // to get the height you want
var width = 1
var height = 1;
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels ( renderTarget, x, y, width, height, heightData );

.. convert heightData back into a height value.
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup. It's very kind to share this skilled expertise. I will work in this direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I managed to implement as your recommand and it works well. However I'm struggling with the packing float / v4  because the texture includes height floats which can be <0 and >1 and the webgl packing float to v4 work for rgb data (between 0 - 1)./ So I apply some quantizing to the height to get a 0-1 float but I think it should be possible to pack the float as it is ... I'll come back when done.