# How to access the float position data stored in a texture?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, textures

I'm using a texture to preprocess some positions data on the gpu for a spring physics simulation. In the program a viewer can click a soft object composed of springs and it will disappear and a different springy object will appear in its place. In order to make the object disappear and a new one appear I need to access during runtime the texture holding the preprocessed positions, alter a part of it, and place it back into the `gl` context.

Right now I am reading out the positions texture using `gl.readPixels`, however instead of seeing the stored float values of the positions I see a variety of rgba values ranging from 0-255. How do I access the float values I've stored in this buffer?

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);

var gl = renderer.context;
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( positionVariable ).texture.__webglFramebuffer);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

The above code produces an array of RGBA 0-255 values - how do I access the values as the position floats I've stored in this texture?

I've also written up this alternate version, but I am unsure how to refer to the texture in the `gl` context (**see starred comment):

```
var pixels = new ArrayBuffer(width * height * 4);
var internalFormat;
var gl = renderer.context;
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, **how do I know my texture ID?** );
gl.getTexLevelParameteriv(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.TEXTURE_COMPONENTS, internalFormat); // get internal format type of GL texture

gl.getTexImage( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
```

three.js v80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you have RGBA texture with 8 bits on each channel. Since bit manipulation is not available in GLSL ES 2.0 you [could pack float in 4 colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882716/packing-float-into-vec4-how-does-this-code-work) and unpack value after gl.readPixels. In three.js you could find packing code in [packing.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/packing.glsl) ShaderChunk.

To render into floating point texture in WebGL 1.0 you need to have [WEBGL_color_buffer_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/) extension enabled, but according to [WebGLStats](http://webglstats.com/) this extension is not widespread.

Also, if all computations are done in vertex shader, another option is encoding your float as depth using [WEBGL_depth_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) extension. It could give you 16bit float (or more).

Comment: I initially create this texture in a fragment shader to do the calculations and then pass it to a second vertex/frag shader pair to use the information to create my simulation. It works great. When I intercept it between these two passes, shouldn't it have all the float info in it already - meaning can I unpack it in the form it's already in? Or is this related to that limitation in GLSL ES 2.0 you described? Thanks!

Comment: Limitation is related to rendering into textures with floating point values. If you do something like `gl_FragColor.rgba = ${my_float}` with default framebuffer (with RGBA8 color) - you write same value into each of four 8-bit channels. If one-channel precision is enough - there is no reason to pack anything. You should get the same value with both reading pixel value on CPU and sampling it in next pass.[gl.readPixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) has parameter `type`, which could help to handle these bits of data in the way you want.